# «se me ficaram (...)», «ficou-se-me (...)», etc

Tags: gramática

Já li várias vezes a expressão 'ficou-se-me (...)'. Quando é que se utiliza esta conjugação pronominal dupla? Eu não sei sequer qual o termo gramatical para uma expressão como essa, mas sempre tive curiosidade em saber em que situações pode justificar-se o seu uso, se existem algumas... Já agora, será que também se pode escrever 'se me ficou' naquelas situações em que há inversão do pronome?

Toda a ajuda seria bastante apreciada.

Comment: Tipo "ficou-se-me atravessado aquele homem"?

Comment: @JorgeB. Pois também interpretei nesse sentido, mas fiquei na dúvida. Alguns exemplos de utilização ou referências seriam úteis.

Comment: Interessante pergunta, também gostaria de saber as complexidades gramaticais por trás dessa construção. Penso que essa utilização dos pronomes é algo informal ou um 'maneirismo' mais utilizado na fala do que na escrita. Parece-me que 'se me ficou' já têm um significado diferente '*Se me ficou mais barato? Isso já não sei*

Comment: @JorgeB. Sim, precisamente... Não me lembrei de nenhum exemplo na altura em que escrevi a pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não há nada de especial em *se-me*, *se-te*, etc.; a combinação de *se* com outro clítico ocorre sempre que se verifiquem simultaneamente as condições para cada um dos clíticos surgir (apenas restrito pelo facto de algumas combinações de clíticos serem impossíveis, como *se-se*, ou marginais/dialetais, como *se-o*).

O clítico *-se* pode ser reflexo, recíproco, ergativo, inerente, apassivador, indeterminador ou apenas enfático, e da mesma forma o pronome dativo (*me/te/lhe/nos/vos/lhes*) pode ter a função de objeto indireto ou ser não argumental (dativo ético, etc.). Assim, a combinação dos dois acaba sendo relativamente comum (o [CETEMPúblico](http://www.linguateca.pt/acesso/corpus.php?corpus=CETEMPUBLICO) tem 2673 entradas para `[lema=".+\+se\+.+"]`). Alguns exemplos:

> par=ext10362-soc-94b-2: Os olhos **enchem-se-lhe** de lágrimas.
>   par=ext22184-opi-98b-1: **Aplica-se-lhe** prisão perpétua?
>   par=ext42294-clt-92b-1: Na verdade, Max Headroom **escapou-se-lhes**.
>   par=ext871530-pol-95b-2: Pediram-lhe autógrafos, falaram com ele, **queixaram-se-lhe** das baixas pensões e uma militante de mais idade confessou agarrar-se à fé para lhe garantir a vitória.

Em relação à segunda pergunta: sim, é possível encontrar *se lhe* se a construção em causa admitir a próclise:

> par=ext30207-nd-95b-2: Na Constituição de 1989 não **se lhe faz** a mínima referência.
>   par=ext690456-clt-95a-2: Mais uma razão para que a voz **se lhe** não **perca** em becos sem futuro.

Comment: Com o condicional é que fica mesmo a matar: *aplicar-se-lhe-ia a prisão perpétua se a lei o permitisse*.

Comment: Não leves a mal, mas para perceber a tua resposta, precisei de ter, ao lado, um dicionário... =D Obrigado pela tua resposta. ;)

Já agora, o que são esses códigos/referências antes de cada exemplo?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. são o código da entrada no CETEMPúblico. Indicam o ano e a secção do jornal.

Comment: Desculpa-me pela minha ignorância, mas para que serve o CETEMPúblico? Tentei ler a página de apresentação, mas não consegui perceber em concreto para que serve esse projecto... calculo que alguém da área tenha maior facilidade.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Vê por exemplo https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corpus_lingu%C3%ADstico